# Use cases for std::remove_if without std::erase

Tags: c++

Considering this simple code that removes values smaller or equal than 6 from a vector of `int`s.

```
int main(void) {
  std::vector<int> v{ 1,3,6,7,8,9 };

  auto x = v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto x) {return x <= 6; }), v.end());

  for (auto & value : v)
    std::cout << value << "\n";
}
```

The code works fine, but I wonder what would be a use case for using `std::remove_if` without erasing the remaining "invalid" elements from the end of the vector.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't one.  If you want to move some elements to the front and don't care about the order of the remaining elements, use `std::partition`.  I'm in the camp that if you use `std::remove_if` to not remove elements then you are lying to the people reading the code.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica the lying part was exactly my thought.

Comment: *what would be a use case for using std::remove_if without erasing the remaining "invalid" elements from the end of the vector.* -- Remember that `std::remove_if` can be used for regular arrays, where you can't erase elements.

Comment: Addendum: You could also use a `filter_view` from ranges-v3/ranges TS/C++20 and have zero cost of moving/copying anything while while still being able to use a ranged based for loop.

Comment: Unlike partition, the tail end elements do not retain the values of the elements removed.  So if they are not erased, they contain (effectively) garbage values.

Answer (score 6):

You might be using for example a `std::array`. Elements cannot be erased from it, but you can use `std::remove_if` to partition "removed" elements to the end (figuratively), and use a pointer to designate last "valid" element (or one past) and possibly destroy the removed elements.

Abstractly, this is still "erasure" though, so I guess my point is that there might not be a pre-existing erasure functionality for a data structure that you use. As such, I would have to conclude that I cannot think of a meaningful use case that doesn't use some form of erasure after "remove".

Note that `std::partition`, while similar, is not the same algorithm. It is more expensive, since it needs to keep elements of both partitions as they are. `std::remove_if` is allowed to clobber the removed elements. Essentially it can use a single move where `std::partition` needs to swap.